# Avoid position getting swapped after executing a query

Tags: mysql

I have a query where i find duplicated players. As we can see on the first screenshot. **id = 1** and **id = 2** has the same players which is equal to **p1** and **p2**.  I have a query now where i can find duplicated players but the problem is the position of the results are getting swapped.

dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/SiEmTIex

Query i used:

```
select s.id, t.* 
from users s
join (
    select LEAST(player1, player2) player1,
           GREATEST(player1, player2) player2, 
           count(*) as qty
    from users
    group by 1, 2
    having count(*) > 1
    ) t on (t.player1, t.player2) IN ((s.player1, s.player2), (s.player2, s.player1))
```

This is my current output:

[image]

My target output (My target here is **least_player1** column data should be equals to **player1**. It goes the same for **player2** and **greatest_player2** :

[image]

Comment: Where's the `ORDER BY` part that should handle this?

Comment: @ErgestBasha I guess I do really need another approach. Any guides for a newbie like me? I'm having a hard time regarding this matter. I thought i can reverse engineer it so that I can swap the positioning but it is not working. :/

Comment: Hello, Sorry. I have another column. COLUMN = pointsp1 and pointsp2 p1 has 1 point and p2 has 2 points And i'm doing the order by like this group by 1, 2 having count(*) > 1 order by pointsp1 ASC

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it